# Variable is different depending where in code it is added

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
html = html + '<img src="img/loaded.gif" alt="" onload="codeAddress("' + arr[i].loc + '");this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" />';
```

which outputs

```
<img src="img/loaded.gif" alt="" onload="codeAddress(" 304-1477="" west="" pender="" street,="" canada");this.parentnode.removechild(this);"="">
```

If I move the variable over like this:

```
html = html + '</div>' + arr[i].loc + '<img src="img/loaded.gif" alt="" onload="codeAddress("");this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" />';
```

I get this:

```
304-1477 West Pender Street, canada<img src="img/loaded.gif" alt="" onload="codeAddress(" ");this.parentnode.removechild(this);"="">
```

Why does the output change based on where the variable is?  Why is

> ""=

Added to every space on the first output?

Comment: this is hard to read, mind splitting it over multiple lines?

Comment: I decided to keep it exactly how I have it in my file because I think the way it is formatted might be causing the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by “move the variable over”? Are you aware your two pieces of code are different by more than just the whitespace?

Comment: If arr[i].loc is outputted like
 onload="codeAddress("' + arr[i].loc + '") 
it outputs as
 codeAddress(" 304-1477="" west="" pender="" street,="" canada") anywhere else it outputs as
 304-1477 West Pender Street, canada

Comment: there isn't enough information here to really understand what's going on.  particularly, the code for `codeAddress` and what the data in `arr` looks like would both be useful information.

Comment: The outputs you've included don't seem to be the contents of the string `html` but rather that string parsed as HTML by the browser. Your first example creates broken HTML because you have quotes within a quoted attribute value. What you're seeing is how the browser parses that broken HTML.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalising your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalised version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable is exactly the same "304-1477 West Pender Street, canada".
In your first case, if you output `html` immediately:

```
html = html + '<img src="img/loaded.gif" alt="" onload="codeAddress("' + arr[i].loc + '");this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" />';
console.log(html); // output html immediately
```

you may get the following from browser's console:

```
<img src="img/loaded.gif" alt="" onload="codeAddress("304-1477 west pender street, canada");this.parentnode.removechild(this);">
```

I guess the output you gave:

```
<img src="img/loaded.gif" alt="" onload="codeAddress(" 304-1477="" west="" pender="" street,="" canada");this.parentnode.removechild(this);"="">
```

is the rendered source from browser, not actual output, because they ("304-1477", "west", "pender", "street,", "canader") look like properties of `<img>`, that's why they followed by `=""`.

Actually you can't use a double quote in such a case, which means `onload="codeAddress("" + someString + "")` won't work as you expect, the correct way is `onload="codeAddress('" + someString +"')` . In order to fix this, you should use single quote here (you need escape chars), like this:

```
html = html + '<img src="img/loaded.gif" alt="" onload="codeAddress(\'' + arr[i].loc + '\');this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
html = html + '</div>' + arr[i].loc + '<img src="img/loaded.gif" alt="" onload="codeAddress(' + "''" + '); this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" />'
```

Your double tick marks in your codeAddress function were causing your markup to be incorrectly parsed.